# Can I check password confirmation in bootstrap 4 with default validation options?

Tags: password-confirmation

I have read https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#validation. After reading I guess it is possible to check confirmation password in client site using bootstrap 4 default options. And, as I new in web development I can't figure out the solution.

If it is possible then how?

My signup modal is

```
<li><button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signUp">Sign Up</button></li>
                    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signIn" style="margin-left:10px">Sign In</button></li>

                    <!-- Modal content-->




                    <div class="modal fade" id="signUp" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Sign Up</h5>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <form>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="email" class="col-form-label">Email address:</label>
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="pwd" class="col-form-label">Password:</label>
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" name="password">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="pwd" class="col-form-label">Confirm Password:</label>
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" name="password">
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

For details code see [this](https://github.com/al2helal/HandicraftStore/blob/master/Web/newnavbar.html)

I want to submit the email and password to server when both password are equal. Otherwise show alert message.

Answer (score 43):

Bootstrap 4 using constraint validation as The following form has two required fields, one for an e-mail address and one for a password. It also has a third field that is only considered valid if the user types the same password in the password field and this third field.

```html
<h1>Create new account</h1>
<form action="/newaccount" method=post
      oninput='up2.setCustomValidity(up2.value != up.value ? "Passwords do not match." : "")'>
  <p>
  <label for="username">E-mail address:</label>
  <input id="username" type=email required name=un>
  <p>
  <label for="password1">Password:</label>
  <input id="password1" type=password required name=up>
  <p>
  <label for="password2">Confirm password:</label>
  <input id="password2" type=password name=up2>
  <p>
  <input type=submit value="Create account">
</form>
```

for more details check: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#sec-constraint-validation